# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't change tag of fragment error when i use navigation drawer(slider menu)

Tags: android, fragment, navigation-drawer, illegalstateexception

I am using slider menu and from one of the fragment's button click am invoking an activity and simply closing the activity when save button is clicked in action bar of that activity. When i click the save button in portrait no error occurs whereas when i keep my device in landscape mode and click save , the following error occurs.

Note:both the fragment and activity are restricted to be in portrait mode. Please someone suggest me with solution.

In Below error ,
Mainactivity --> activity that holds all the fragments in slider. 
Settings fragment --> its the fragment from which am invoking an activity. 
Home--> its the initial main fragment in slider, i mean default fragment as soon as the main activity is being invoked.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.symtrac_loc.tr/com.novartis.symtrac.slider.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't change tag of fragment FragmentSettings{433cf7e0 #2 id=0x7f0900fa SETTINGS}: was SETTINGS now HOME
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3924)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:161)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1271)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't change tag of fragment FragmentSettings{433cf7e0 #2 id=0x7f0900fa SETTINGS}: was SETTINGS now HOME
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.doAddOp(BackStackRecord.java:398)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.replace(BackStackRecord.java:429)
            at com.novartis.symtrac.slider.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:134)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5426)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3924)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:161)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1271)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: can you show me the code?

Comment: Which part of the code do you want me to put on .. Actually its a bunk of code. So specifically which part do you need?

Comment: Post the "save button" clickListener code, and how you add/call your fragments.